# How to use roslyn in a vsix project? Could not find a part of the path csc.exe

Tags: c#, roslyn, vsix

I installed the nuget package using the package manager and:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```

( from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform )

But when I go to call:

CompileAssemblyFromFile on a Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider

I get the following error message:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\bin\\roslyn\\csc.exe'
```

Comment: Why are you using CodeDom at all? You should use Roslyn APIs directly.

Comment: Indeed; I think the CodeDomProvider is really mostly for ASP.NET support.

Comment: I had some code that was using this before roslyn was around.  I tried moving some of that code into a VSIX and hit the problem above.  I have been able to replace the code with Roslyn code.